# Springboot Integration Test - Unwanted Mocks

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to write integration test for SpringBoot application. code looks something like below

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class, MyTestConfig.class})
@ActiveProfile("test")
class MyIntegrationTest {

@Autowire
ServiceInterface serviceA;

}
```

I noticed that applicationContext loads some of the service beans as Mockito mocked object which really defeats the purpose of Integration test as it does not execute some of the code. Can anyone suggest what could be wrong here. Please note that some of the services being autowired correctly but some are being mocked. I do not see any logical reason why they behaves differently since they are implemented same way. I am using spring boot 2.0.3

Already tried.

Removed MyTestConfig.class but problem remains same. Even if I use @SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class, MyProblematicServiceImpl.class}), It still returns mocked object wherever it is autowired. MyProblematicServiceImpl is empty class annotated with @Service.

Comment: You have to check at Application.class and MyTestConfig.class, and see what beans are being mocked by Mockito. If there are mockito mocks that's because the integration tests dont want to execute real service. Let's say that the mockito mock is avoiding the test to run a 3rd party service... so for that particular test you can just avoid that and continue. Some integration tests just want to test your app and not involve other companies services.

Comment: It is same internal service, I cannot understand why spring-boot test mocks it by default. If I want to mock any bean, I would use @MockBean. I am struggling to get why some classes are getting mocked not all. How can I let spring-boot avoid mocking services

Comment: What does the MyTestConfig class look like? SpringBootTest does support mocking services, but they'd have to be annotated MockBean, unless something is going horribly wrong in Spring.

Comment: I removed MyTestConfig.class but problem remains same. MyTestConfig class was there to support a Stub implementation, it had only one bean. The problem i am getting it is not for the same bean. Even if I use @SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class, MyProblematicServiceImpl.class}), It still returns mocked object wherever it is autowired. MyProblematicServiceImpl is empty class annotaioned with @Service.

Comment: My guess is that Application results in a component scan, which is picking up a test config you have. You may have to exclude some test configurations.

Comment: @Seth, this was exactly the issue. There was a test under unit test which has inner class to load some mocked configuration and it was getting scanner as part of ComponentScan process in integration test as well.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications), if you set the webEnvironment setting on the SpringBootTest annotation to something other than MOCK, the default, then it will start up a real web environment.

Comment: I noticed that in doc but using NONE did not work either

Comment: I do not want to run in web environment, it is kind of standalone application

Answer (score 1):

Promoting from the comments, so it’s answered.

The Application results in a component scan, which is picking up a test config you have. You may have to exclude some test configurations.

Spring Boot provides @TestConfiguration to solve this issue.

Comment: TestConfigutation will not work as Integration and Unit test both can scan the same configuration. I will adapt not to use Inner class for testconfiguration as it hides things from manual check